# @ngrx/schematics fail when generate anctions and reducers

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ngrx, angular-schematics

I just installed @ngrx/schematics to enable me to generate `reducers` and `actions` with **angular CLI** in an existing app in what I am using @ngrx/store. I use the command `yar add @ngrx/schematics` and then I configured to use instead of angular schematics with `ng config cli.defaultCollection @ngrx/schematics` which add the configuration to my angular JSON file. all seems to be good. common classes like components and services are created successfully but, I am getting errors when I try to create actions or reducers.

[image]

I am using angular 6 and ngrx/schematics 8.3

```
"@ngrx/schematics": "^8.3.0",
"@ngrx/store": "6.0.1",
```

[image]

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by myself. If anyone has this issue you can solve by downgrade your '@ngrx/shcematics' to '6.1.2'